# Elixir characters being treated as integers, not characters when splitting to head and tail

Tags: elixir

I'm working on a basic problem with elixir - RNA transcription. However I'm hitting some unexpected (to me) behavior with my solution:

```
defmodule RnaTranscription do
  @doc """
  Transcribes a character list representing DNA nucleotides to RNA

  ## Examples

  iex> RnaTranscription.to_rna('ACTG')
  'UGAC'
  """
  @spec to_rna([char]) :: [char]
  def to_rna(dna) do
    _to_rna(dna)
  end

  def _to_rna([]), do: ''
  def _to_rna([head | tail]), do: [_rna(head) | _to_rna(tail)]

  def _rna(x) when x == 'A', do: 'U' 
  def _rna(x) when x == 'C', do: 'G'
  def _rna(x) when x == 'T', do: 'A'
  def _rna(x) when x == 'G', do: 'C'
end
```

When the solution is run, I get errors as the _rna function is being invoked with an integer that does not match the guard clause instead of the character.

```
The following arguments were given to RnaTranscription._rna/1:

        # 1
        65

    lib/rna_transcription.ex:18: RnaTranscription._rna/1
    lib/rna_transcription.ex:16: RnaTranscription._to_rna/1
```

Is there a way to force elixir to keep the value as a character when it splits into head and tail?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ naming public functions starting with underscore is counter-idiomatic. Use `defp` for private functions and call them `do_rna` not `_rna`, which is conventional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the difference between a list `'A'` and a character `?A` perfectly answered by Michael, this code has one more hidden but important glitch.

You use recursion that is not tail-optimized, which should be avoided at any cost. It might in general lead to stack overflow. Below is the TCO code.

```rb
defmodule RnaTranscription do
  def to_rna(dna), do: do_to_rna(dna)

  defp do_to_rna(acc \\ [], []), do: Enum.reverse(acc)
  defp do_to_rna(acc, [char | tail]),
    do: do_to_rna([do_char(char) | acc], tail)

  defp do_char(?A), do: ?U 
  defp do_char(?C), do: ?G
  defp do_char(?T), do: ?A
  defp do_char(?G), do: ?C
end

RnaTranscription.to_rna('ACTG')
#⇒ 'UGAC'
```

or, even better, with a comprehension

```rb
converter = fn
  ?A -> ?U 
  ?C -> ?G
  ?T -> ?A
  ?G -> ?C
end

for c <- 'ACTG', do: converter.(c)         
#⇒ 'UGAC'
```

You might even filter it inplace.

```rb
for c when c in 'ACTG' <- 'ACXXTGXX',
  do: converter.(c)         
#⇒ 'UGAC'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `?` code point operator:

```
  def _rna(x) when x == ?A, do: 'U'
  def _rna(x) when x == ?C, do: 'G'
  def _rna(x) when x == ?T, do: 'A'
  def _rna(x) when x == ?G, do: 'C'
```

Strictly speaking, Elixir is already keeping the value as a character! A character is a code point, which is an integer. When you match on `'A'`, you are matching on a charlist, which is a list of integers. That is, you are trying to match `65` to `[65]`.